# How do I refresh the jquery textbox autocomplete array?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I heard there is no such thing as a goto statement.  I probably need to stuff the JSON and array.push with in a function.  Does that sound correct?  Would I also need to call the function within a .change statement.

http://jsfiddle.net/w2QHz/4/

```
var tagsArray = []

$.getJSON("https://api.deckbrew.com/mtg/cards/typeahead?q=" + tags.value,function(result){
  $.each(result, function(i, field){
    tagsArray.push(field.name);
  });

  $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: tagsArray
  });  

  $( "#tags" ).change({
      // do some
  });

  });
```

Comment: I'd say: yes and yes.

Comment: Or you could simply use a remote datasource... http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Comment: How do I successfully add the deckbrew json link as a remote source, indexed by name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to return the JSON string as data for the `autocomplete` is to use a [remote datasource](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source). Here's an example:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    "source": function (request, response) {
        var term = request.term || ''; // default to empty string
        $.getJSON('https://api.deckbrew.com/mtg/cards/typeahead', {
            "q": term
        }, function (data, status, xhr) {
            var names = data.map(function (value, index, array) {
                return value.name; // iterate through data and build new array from name
            }).sort(); // sort it
            response(names); // send it to autocomplete to use as datasource
        });
    }
});
```

and as applied to your [updated] fiddle:

### http://jsfiddle.net/w2QHz/7/

Comment: Maybe you could now point me into the correct direction.  how can I hyperlink a result, e.g. .append(th.clone().html("<a href='" + value.editions[0].url + "'>Click Here</a>")) and then pass that url onto a JSON link and function like the one found in 'button'.

Comment: This sounds like a perfect opportunity to post another question. http://jsfiddle.net/w2QHz/11/ should get you started.